# Can Unity be uninstalled?

Tags: 11.10, unity, gnome-classic

Recently when doing an update, I noticed I was downloading a bunch of packages related to Unity. I use Gnome-Classic, and have no intention of ever using Unity.

So, I thought I might save myself some bandwidth and download times (which can be slow on my laptop) by removing Unity.

However, on next reboot, I could not get any form of GUI interface. Only by reinstalling Unity was I able to get the log in interface and get back into Gnome Classic.

Can I get rid of Unity, or is it somehow now integral to Ubuntu in a way that makes Ubuntu not run without it (even if I'm exlusively using Gnome-Classic)?

Comment: How, specifically, did you remove Unity?

Comment: @EliahKagan: I went into Synaptic and removed what seemed to be the main Unity packages. I'm sorry, but I can't remember what packages exactly.

Comment: You can find out what you removed by examining the contents of `/var/log/dpkg.log` (then you can edit your post to include a description of what you did and a list of the specific packages removed). If you have trouble figuring it out from that (sometimes it's confusing, especially if a number of subsequent package management operations have been performed since), please post the entire contents of the file at [Ubuntu Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and edit your post to include a link to it.

Comment: @EliahKagan: I checked /var/log/dpkg.log, but it seems to not go back far enough. This was actually a couple weeks ago that I did this. I opened it in gedit and searched for "unity", but the only mention was from a couple days ago, which wasn't the time I tried uninstalling it. :(

Comment: Can I steer this in a different direction and ask: What *should* I uninstall if I want to uninstall Unity (and leave my system intact)?

Comment: Apart from `libunity6` and `unity-greeter[if you use lightdm]` you can remove everything else related to unity using quickfilter in synaptic and also `compiz-core` if you don't use `compiz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is `Yes`. Basically `Unity` is just a shell on top of `gnome3` so you can use any desktop environment you like.

The login screen you are talking about is not `unity` but `lightdm`. Ubuntu uses `lightdm` and the default theme used is `unity-greeter` which is independent of unity. So make sure lightdm as well as unity-greeter is installed and choose your session. Basically what you can do is change default setting of lightdm with `/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults` and lightdm also offers another gtk theme called `lightdm-gtk-greeter` if you dislike the default login screen.

you may set default session and greeter

```
/var/lib/lightdm/lighdm-set-defaults -s YourSessionName
/var/lib/lightdm/lighdm-set-defaults -g lightdm-gtk-greeter/unity-greeter
```

Or you may opt to choose a completely different display manager i.e. GDM, LXDM or Slim

`gdm used to be display manager prior 11.10`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and I'm sure you're mostly right, but I'm not 100% we are talking about the same things. When I say I couldn't get a GUI of any kind, I didn't mean just the login screen. I meant I couldn't start any X sesssion even after logging in at the command prompt. Anyway, I think you're on the right track that it's a matter of the GDM... does Gnome/Gnome-Classic not run on lightdm? I'm a little confused with your answer if you're saying I need to have gdm or lightdm in order to use Gnome-Classic.

Comment: As far as I know it should. what do you get when you run `sudo restart/start lightdm` ? or you may try to reconfigure lightdm `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`. I am just saying you do have other choices if `lightdm` is not working for you.

Comment: I don't seem to have lighdm installed. I only have gdm. So... if I try and remove Unity, I should make sure it doesn't accidentally uninstall gdm, and I should be okay?

Comment: yep, try reconfiguring gdm so that its the default display manager and you are good to go